# Getting number of occurrences per year

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
          IncidntNum     Category      Date                    
1         150098210        ROBBERY     02/03/2011 12:00:00 AM             
2         150098210        ASSAULT     07/05/2013 12:00:00 AM
4         150098226      VANDALISM     12/01/2015 12:00:00 AM
7         150098248      VANDALISM     04/06/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

And I'm interested in figuring out how many times a certain crime occurs every year, so that I would e.g. be able to make a graph for every type of crime, showing how many times that crime has occurred every year. How would I go about doing that? I'm a little lost on the steps to get there to be honest.

So far I've imported the CSV file and plotted how many crimes simply occur and plotted that on a graph showing me occurances of each type of crime.

```
with open("file.csv", 'r') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)

    crimes = data.loc[data['Category'] == x]
    crimes_dates = crimes['Date']
    crimes_year = crimes_dates.apply(lambda x: x[6:10]).value_counts().sort_index()
    unique_crimes_years = crimes_year.value_counts()
    unique_crimes_years.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.ylabel("Crimes count")
    plt.show()
```

Which is fine and all, but I'd like to be able to pick out a certain crime and plot how many times that crime occurs each year.

```
crimes = data.loc[data['Category'] == 'VANDALISM'
```

This would get me a new DataFrame similar to `data` with but only with 'VANDALISM', but I'm a little stuck as to how I can plot it relative to year?

EDIT:

As suggested by Henry, extracting the year and then counting by year has been added and attempted plotted.

EDIT 2:

Sorted the year by index as well so we get the correct order of years.

Comment: Extract the year from the date string, and then count by year.

Comment: That seems to be a major step in the right direction, but is there another way than using `value_counts()` as it seems to sort by occurrences, such that the year with the least occurrences at the left, going up, whereas I'd like to sort by the year instead?

Comment: honestly, id personally preproc that out in SQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `groupby` and count while having the date as your index:

## In

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date')
df.groupby(df.index.year).count()
```

## Out

```
      IncidntNum  Category
2011           1         1
2013           1         1
2015           2         2
```

## Plot:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year).count()['IncidntNum'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

If you want them grouped by both category and year:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year,'Category']).count()['IncidntNum'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Let's throw in a unstack for good measure:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year,'Category']).count()['IncidntNum'].unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]